# How to display the time elapsed in a label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

What should be straight forward is not here and I couldnt find a way yet in spite of reading a lot.

I have a button which executes a time consuming function. So on clicking the button should show time elapsed in milliseconds in a label with an interval of 500 ms. And when the desired result is achieved I want the timer to stop. **I dont just need the final time (the total time consumed) in a label, but the label should dynamically show the time being elapsed.** My code would be:

```
    private void btnHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.StartClock(ref label12);

        Utility.PopulateHistory(dgvRecords_history, _util); //time consuming function

        c.StopClock();
    }
```

And in `Class1` I write this:

```
    internal void StartClock(ref Label l)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 500;
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Tag = l;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    int i;
    bool stop;
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stop)
        {
            ((Timer)sender).Stop();
            return;
        }

        ((Label)((Timer)sender).Tag).Text = (++i).ToString();
    }

    internal void StopClock()
    {
        i = 0;
        stop = true;
    }
```

What happens is, the `t_Tick` event is fired only after the complete code under button event is fired. That is the tick event is fired after it goes through the StopClock function! I got no idea why on earth it should be that!

2 questions basically:

1. How can my requirement be achieved in the right way to handle these? I know I should use other built in classes to evaluate performance, but this is just for display purpose. For this, what is the ideal approach?
2. Why is my code not working?

EDIT: I have used here `System.Windows.Forms Timer` here, but the result is not any different with `System.Timers Timer`

Comment: are you sure that t_Tick is only being fired ONCE? did you actually debug it?

Comment: @Shai, no its fired continuously without stop after getting out from StopClock function. But since I have given an if clause to stop the timer, ya it stops the timer readily and hence ticks only once. Hope you get me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your long-running task is also running on the UI thread. So the timer can't fire and update the UI, since the thread is busy handling the long-running task.

Instead, you should use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to handle the long-running task.

In code:

```
private void btnHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Class1 c = new Class1(ref label12); 
    c.StartClock(); 

    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            // time consuming function
            Utility.PopulateHistory(dgvRecords_history, _util);
        };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            c.StopClock();
        };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

As ChrisWue noted, since you now have the long-running task in a separate thread, it needs to invoke any access to the UI controls on the UI thread.

If your long-running task just needs some data from the UI to start, you can pass that data as parameter of `RunWorkerAsync()`. If you need to output some result data to the UI, you can do that in the handler of the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. If you occasionally need to update the UI as progress is being made, you can do that in the handler of the `ProgressChanged` event, calling `ReportProgress()` in your DoWork handler.

If none of the above are needed, you could use the ThreadPool, as in StaWho's answer.

Comment: Ok, in that case, what is a timer a really meant for? After all we generally execute the entire program on one thread right?

Comment: @nawfal: Running code periodically. If you need multiple threads, you use multiple threads. This is completely orthogonal with a timer.

Comment: We often execute the entire program on one thread since it is easier to understand and manage. However, in this case you want two things happening at the same time: Run your long-running function and update the UI. You can either do that manually (i.e. in your function occasionally update the UI) or do it "automatically" via 2 threads.

Comment: @Daniel You should mention in your answer that it is not safe to access the UI from the background worker directly but all UI access needs to be marshalled back to the UI thread.

Comment: @DanielRose why is your code giving compilation error. Seems curly brackets are not implemented properly

Comment: When your code executed I get an exception saying `Cross threaded operation not valid` and one of my panel is being accessed from a different thread. Anyway i have lost hopes on this :)

Comment: The background worker runs on a different thread, so if you need to access something from the UI, you either need to give the needed data as parameter when starting the worker (if you just need an initial value) or invoke on the UI thread. For more details, see the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: @DanielRose can you tell me what exactly are the variables s and e doing here?

Comment: @nawfal I wrote the event handlers inline, using the lambda syntax. s and e are the sender and event arguments, which I am not using in this case.

Comment: @Daniel Rose oh ok, so it need not be s and e, but anything like p and q.. Got it..

Answer (score 2):

Your time consuming function is blocking the main thread. You can use `BackgroundWorker` or below trick:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t.Tick +=new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Interval = 500;
    }

    int timeElapsed = 0;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Start();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
        {
            TimeConsumingFunction();
        });

    }

    void TimeConsumingFunction()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        t.Stop();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeElapsed += t.Interval;
        label1.Text = timeElapsed.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: With a BackgroundWorker you can explicitly update the UI (in the ProgressChanged handler). If that isn't needed, you can use the ThreadPool instead. Note that in .NET 4.5 it will be even easier due to the new async API.

Answer (score 0):

Add the timer to the Components collection of the form. Or store the timer in a field in the class.

The timer is garbage collected because it is not longer reachable when your method returns.

I don't know about your long running code, but out should new run on a separate thread, or make calls to Application.DoEvents

(And remove the ref in your code, it is not used).

Comment: Let me see to that, thanks..i know about ref, but was being doubly cautious when  I saw no response on the label

Comment: How to add a separately created timer to Controls collection? I tired with `Controls.Add()`, but it says Timer is not valid Control

Answer (score 0):

@Dainel Rose's answer worked for me perfectly, but only if invalid cross thread operation is handled. I could do so like:

```
private void btnHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Class1 c = new Class1(ref label12); 
    c.StartClock(); 

    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += ((s, e) =>
        {
            // time consuming function
            Utility.PopulateHistory(dgvRecords_history, _util);
        });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += ((s, e) =>
        {
            c.StopClock();
        });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And in the `Utility` class where the time consuming function runs,

```
    internal static void PopulateHistory(DataGridView dgv, Utility util)
    {
        SetDataGridView_History(dgv, util);
    }

    delegate void UpdateDataGridView_History(DataGridView dgv, Utility util);
    static void SetDataGridView_History(DataGridView dgv, Utility util)
    {
        if (dgv.InvokeRequired)
        {
            UpdateDataGridView_History updaterDelegate = new UpdateDataGridView_History(SetDataGridView_History);
            ((Form)util._w).Invoke(updaterDelegate, new object[] { dgv, util });
        }
        else
            //code that utilizes UI thread (long running process in my case)
    }
```

Thanks all who helped. I'm marking Daniel's answer..